# Killing Ulysses after talking him down, Fallout NV

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I really disliked Ulysses in the Lonesome Road DLC but I did not want to deal with Marked Men alone. I talked him down and after he killed everyone I put 30 plasma mines under his feet and exploded them. Somehow, he did not die. Then I headshotted him at point blank range a few times from YCS 186 but he stil did not die. Is it true that he can not be killed after you decide to side with him?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately yes, he is marked "essential" after you decided to team up with him during the enemy waves, which is a good decision because  [he is basically immortal.](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Ulysses)